# Load already fetched image when offline in Glide for Android

Tags: android, image, android-glide

Am using Glide version 4.8.0

And for loading an image I do this

```
GlideApp
    .with(HomePageFragment.this)
    .load(remoteURL)
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
    .into(mImageView);
```

When the device is connected to Internet the image loades successfully but when device goes **offline**, how to load the same image from cache that was already featched from the `remoteURL`?

My CustomAppGlideModule looks like this

```
@GlideModule
public class CustomAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {

    @Override
    public void applyOptions(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull GlideBuilder builder) {
        builder.setMemoryCache(new LruResourceCache(20 * 1024 * 1024));
        builder.setDiskCache(new InternalCacheDiskCacheFactory(context, 100 * 1024 * 1024));
    }

}
```

I also tried

```
.onlyRetrieveFromCache(true)
```

But that also does not help.

Comment: can you please try it with Glide.with(mContext)
   .load(url)
   .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
   .into(imageView);

Comment: insted of DiskCacheStrategy.ALL use SOURCE

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Option 1:** 
Use DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE instead of DiskCacheStrategy.ALL it should work because of DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE saves the original data to cache.

```
//Version 4.x
GlideApp
    .with(HomePageFragment.this)
    .load(remoteURL)
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.DATA)
    .into(mImageView);

//Version 3.x
Glide.with(mContext)
   .load(url)
   .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
   .into(imageView);
```

**Option 2:** (if above does not work)

Any specific reason for using Glide? Would you like to give a shot to Picasso, I found Picasso much better for this. You may use the following code for offline caching. It will first serve from offline if not found then search for online image.

```
Picasso.with(getActivity())
.load(imageUrl)
.networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
.into(imageView, new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
      //..image loaded from cache
    }

    @Override
    public void onError() {
        //Try again online if cache failed
        Picasso.with(getActivity())
                .load(posts.get(position).getImageUrl())
                .error(R.drawable.header)
                .into(imageView, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
              //... image loaded from online
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                Log.v("Picasso","Could not fetch image");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually i found the error, it was at some other place. And yes I use glide cause it does not require to resize image for `centerCrop()` and also provide many other built in facilities. AND the most important is the caching mechanism of it.

Comment: oh thanks for sharing the knowledge. Can you please edit the answer, with the solution you found to make this question productive for others. If you found helpful please upvote.