# how to save image in cache?

Tags: android, kotlin, imageview

I want to when user is offline, the image from firebase storage that retrived in an imageview when he/she was online, be visible, but I can't implement that codes, as a beginner in android studio and kotlin.

I want add Glide image cache and loader to this :

```
private fun getUserProfile() {
    val navigationView = binding.navView
    val header: View = navigationView.getHeaderView(0)
    storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("Users/$uid")
    val localeFile = File.createTempFile("tempFile","")
    storageReference.getFile(localeFile).addOnSuccessListener {
        val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localeFile.absolutePath)
        val imageView = header.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.circleImageView)
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
    }.addOnFailureListener{
        finish()
    }
}
```

but I don't know how to add below codes to above one correctly :

```
Glide.with(this)
.load(url)
.into(imageView);
```

I added like below but in offline still not load :

```
private fun getUserProfile() {
    val navigationView = binding.navView
    val header: View = navigationView.getHeaderView(0)
    storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("Users/$uid")
    val localeFile = File.createTempFile("tempFile","")
    storageReference.getFile(localeFile).addOnSuccessListener {
        val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localeFile.absolutePath)
        val imageView = header.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.circleImageView)
        Glide.with(this)
            .load(bitmap)
            .into(imageView)
    }.addOnFailureListener{
        finish()
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53140975/load-already-fetched-image-when-offline-in-glide-for-android

Comment: usefull but not solved the main focused broblem. but thank you     @UsamaAltaf

Comment: Convert image to Base64 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830711/how-can-i-convert-an-image-into-a-base64-string

Comment: it changed nothing, but thank you :) so what should I do I search and read and tried too many ways today but no one of them solved but all articles are related to this :(